# Python warnings in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis-3, python-3

I just opened the QGIS and this appeared. What does it mean? Is it serious problems?

1. warning:/Applications/QGIS3.6.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py:672: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
             mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
2. warning:/Applications/QGIS3.6.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/PyQt5/uic/objcreator.py:152: DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated
             plugin = open(filename, 'rU')
3. warning:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py:144: UserWarning:

The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see:

[image]

Comment: Some information on what you were trying to do, when these errors showed up, would be rather helpful.

Comment: Hi, yes sorry was in a rush to post a question. Hope it explains better now.

Comment: Look a   [python warnings — Warning control¶](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) or   [warnings – Non-fatal alerts](https://pymotw.com/2/warnings/)